# Can I send money to my friend's Steam wallet?

Tags: steam

I would like to send someone who already has a Steam account a money gift so that he can buy himself some games.

Is this possible? If so, how?

Answer (score 29):

There is no option to send money to the wallet of your friend directly.

What you can do however, is buy a Steam gift card at [GameStop](http://www.gamestop.com/collection/steam-cards) and send that code to your buddy so he can [activate](https://store.steampowered.com/account/redeemwalletcode) it. I do not know if that works cross countries though. But if you both live in the same country and GameStop has those gift cards available, then it would be no problem to activate it.

Another option would be to put an TF2 item on the [Steam Market](http://steamcommunity.com/market/) and you buy that. Valve takes a cut here though, so it is not really viable and I don't recommend it.

The best option imho would be just to ask him what game he wants and gift that directly.

Answer (score 15):

Steam recently added the ability to [buy digital gift cards online](http://store.steampowered.com/digitalgiftcards/), which is effectively what you need here.

Answer (score 14):

You can send your friend money via PayPal. Steam accepts PayPal as a form of payment.

Comment: You can also send him a Steam Wallet code via PayPal Digital Gifts, so he doesn't need to have a paypal account (I had to do this yesterday for a friend without paypal) https://www.paypal-gifts.com/us/brands/steam-digital-wallet-code.html

Comment: @JamesManning: Great, limited to a couple of countries T_T

Answer (score 2):

> so that he can choose himself some games.

Slightly redefining the stated problem, that's what the Steam wishlist is for. If you have him as a friend on steam, and he has items on his wishlist, you can gift him those.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question at hand. This should have been a comment.

Comment: Until @clamp clarifies his question, I'm choosing to stick by my answer. This is a valid alternative.

Comment: +1. This is a perfectly valid workaround and definitely within the realm of value exchanging hands over steam. Just because the question states money does not make this an invalid point

Comment: Wishlist might be dangerous, unless you confirm it with him first. For myself, my wishlist is merely a reminder of things I might be interested in -- it doesn't necessarily list everything (like just a single game but I'd take the bundle if it goes on 'daily deal' or something like that), and I might not even buy THAT game, but choose a similar one instead. Or it's just something that looked interesting, but I haven't had time to take a closer look at it so I don't even know whether I want it.

Comment: @ChristianStieber It's a fair warning, but in the end, other people can hardly be faulted if someone misuses the wishlist in that manner. My dad used to use the Outlook's Trash folder as an "emails I might read later" folder, until I emptied it once.